# highcharts inside ng-repeat (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

When we have multiple charts (using highcharts) on the same page and we want to make it inside a loop. Doesn't work.

Classic case (it works properly):

```
<div ng-attr-id="container1"
        style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; max-width: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <div id="container2"
        style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; max-width: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Specific case: in a loop

```
<div ng-repeat-n="2">
    <div ng-attr-id="container{{$index+3}}"
        style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; max-width: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</div>
```

[Example runing](http://jsfiddle.net/riadh/a53yy0wz/1/).

Comment: As I see your container doenst return correct value, becasue your ID is container{{n}} instaed of container3

Comment: yes I noticed that, but ng-repeat "n in [3,4]" works fine on my local machine (it displays container3) and i have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, when I put the highcharts inside the nested views 
in my example i choose angular-route-segment

```
<div app-view-segment="0"></div>
```

and when i put the highcharts outside the nested view it works correctly.